# Bootstrap scrollspy not working with jQuery plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, scrollspy

**UPDATE**: Seems like this only doesn't work on my computer, with any browser. On other computers it works just fine.

Demo: http://yosefw.me/2001/01/01/test.html

I'm using Jekyll & GitHub pages to host my personal website.

I wanted to add a 'Table of contents' functionality to my posts. I tried to use this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/ghiculescu/jekyll-table-of-contents

It seems it's somehow conflicting with Bootstrap's scrollspy, as it doesn't highlight (add ".active") to the relevant nav items as a I scroll. I think it's a problem with the plugin, because it worked fine when I removed it and hard-coded the table of contents.

Other files that might be relevant:

- My default template: https://github.com/yosefw/yosefw.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/default.html
- My post template: https://github.com/yosefw/yosefw.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/post.html
- My main JS file: https://github.com/yosefw/yosefw.github.io/blob/master/js/main.js

How can I solve this and make the scrollspy work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this unnecessary jquery plugin and use [automatic toc generation provided with kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html#toc)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This plugin is really lightweight and specific to my problem. I'm looking for a way to make it work before I go back and look into alternatives.